# Convert dictionary containing `Any?` to `AnyObject`?

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a straightforward way of converting a dictionary of type `[String : Any?]` to a dictionary of `[String: AnyObject]`. I could loop through the elements individually, but that just seems 'wrong' to me.

If I just try to cast the original dictionary, I get a crash.

```
let dict:[String : Any?] = ["something" : "else"]

// crashes with fatal error: 'can't unsafeBitCast 
// between types of different sizes'
let newDict = dict as? [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looping is exactly correct, and Swift encourages this. The most efficient and Swift-like (*) approach is:

```
var result = [String: AnyObject]()
for (key, value) in dict {
    if let v = value as? AnyObject {
        result[key] = v
    }
}
```

(*) This isn't really "Swift-like" because it includes `AnyObject`, which should almost never be part of a non-temporary data structure. A proper Swift implementation would convert `AnyObject` to a real type.

Note that the crash you get is definitely not appropriate and you should open a radar (bugreport.apple.com). An `as?` should never crash like this. You should either get `nil` or a compiler failure.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: as @rob-napier mentioned in the comments, its O(n^2) so this approach is only valid for small dictionaries (less than 100 elements).*

You can use `reduce`:

```
let dict:[String : Any?] = ["something" : "else"]

let newDict = dict.reduce([String: AnyObject](), combine: { accumulator, pair in
    var temp = accumulator
    temp[pair.0] = pair.1 as? AnyObject
    return temp
})
```

Here `newDict` is of type `[String: AnyObject]`.

Comment: This approach is O(n^2). Every time you add a new element, you make a copy of the entire dictionary. For small dictionaries (less than 100 elements), it doesn't matter much. But for anything larger than that, this is incredibly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer.